# Website suddenly start giving error as website is not secured i.e https stops working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, server, virtualhost

I am running a website on Ubuntu, apache server and my website is running fine till last night and it suddenly start giving not secure error i.e when accessing using https it is giving error (ssl was  installed 1 day back only).  When accessing without http it is redirecting to https.

So I reinstall my ssl certificate from certbot, and I did not select all redirect traffic to https. I thought there is some configuration error with ssl so http should work. But issue did not resolve.

Then I thought issue is with my configuration so I checked my logs and I found some errors like -

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>
> AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/

Such errors are there in my error logs, I am using one virtual host and I have disable the default conf in site-available.

My virtual host file content is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex home.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

In place of domain I am using my original domain name.

This is my /etc/hosts entry

```
127.0.1.1 domain.com domain
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Then I try to change the ip 127.0.1.1 with my server ip address and then I reinstall my ssl certificate using command:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d domain.com -d www.domain.com
```

It says ssl successfully install but when I try to access my website it is still not working and showing ssl error or when i try without ssl it says access forbidden.

What I understand from logs is that it is not searching my file directory `/var/www/domain/` it is searching file directory of default configuration which I disabled `/var/www/html/`.

So to solve the issue temporary I enabled default host file and changed the directory from `/var/www/html/` this to `/var/www/domain/` and below in `domain.com.conf` and `domain.com-le-ssl.conf` host file I changed https to http

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

So website start working for http and redirecting all traffic from https to http. But I need to install ssl and want to make all configuration proper. Can anyone help me out to solve this issue!

Edit -

here is my vhost 443 entry

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    
        <Directory /var/www/domain/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex home.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/letsfindcourse.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/letsfindcourse.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `giving not secure error` ... `showing ssl error` .. What is the error?  Be specific, this is the one thing you are trying to solve, copy-paste the exact error msg you are seeing.

Comment: You have shown us the http/80 vhost config, but that is working fine, right? The problem is with the https/443 vhost, so where is that config?

Comment: please check - I have added that also now. @Don'tPanic

Comment: 1) Why are you redirecting https to https?  2) I will ask again - what is the error you are trying to fix?  Be specific, this is the one thing you are trying to solve, copy-paste the exact error msg you are seeing.